# Flutter - Cannot add custom menu in fluent ui textbox

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, user-controls

I am trying to add to a TextBox a custom menu through contextmenubuilder but seems  it has no effects and I am not able to add anything.

I have tried to follow the send email example in this doc https://pub.dev/documentation/fluent_ui/latest/fluent_ui/TextBox/contextMenuBuilder.html
but with no effect, here my code

```
//the print statement is there to see if code has reched certain points
TextBox(
                    controller: controllerBody,
                    placeholder: 'Insert ',
                    contextMenuBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        EditableTextState editableTextState) {
                      final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttons =
                          editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
                      final TextEditingValue value = controllerBody.value;
                      String text = value.selection.textInside(value.text);
                      if (_isValid(text)) {
                        print(text);
                        buttons.insert(
                          0,
                          ContextMenuButtonItem(
                            label: 'Send email',
                            onPressed: () {
                              ContextMenuController.removeAny();
                              print('ollo');
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                              anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                              buttonItems: buttons);
                    },
                  ),

bool _isValid(text) {
  print(text);
  return text == 'finanza';
}
```